# Dynamic Pivotting in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, count, pivot

I'd like get a count of every possible value from one table associated with each possible value from another table. So if my (combined) table basically look like:

```
Order ID     Employee      Product Category
-------------------------------------------
1             Alan          Automobile
2             Barry         Beauty
3             Charlie       Clothing
4             Alan          Beauty
```

I would like to be able to query and get a result of:

```
Employee     Count Auto     Count Beauty     Count Clothing
------------------------------------------------------------
Alan         1              1                0
Barry        0              1                0
Charlie      0              0                1
```

I could manually query for each count, but then if I later add new product categories, it will no longer work. What I'm doing now is basically just:

```
SELECT employee, category, COUNT(*) FROM sales GROUP BY employee, category;
```

Which returns:

```
Employee     Category     Count
-------------------------------
Alan         Automobile   1
Alan         Beauty       1
Alan         Clothing     0
```

etc. But with a large number of categories this can get a bit redundant. Is there any way to have it returned as a single row for each employee with a column for every category?

Comment: Can the "count" be more than 1? Would really seem like a boolean flag? (In which case, there is a faster way). Also, do you query for a single employee or for all at once?

Comment: Yes, the count will almost always be more than 1. It's querying for all at once to see the total number of items each employee has sold in each category.

Comment: Would two arrays (categories, counts) or one 2-dimensional array or a JSON document per employee do the job, too? Those are all possible without dynamic SQL ...

Comment: So please clarify: do you need distinct columns in the result or are you happy with the JSON document demonstrated by Derviş.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JSON approach

```
SELECT employee,
  json_object_agg(ProductCategory,total ORDER BY ProductCategory)
FROM (
 SELECT employee, ProductCategory, count(*) AS total
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY employee,ProductCategory
) s
GROUP BY employee
ORDER BY employee;
```

or with two step approach

```
CREATE FUNCTION dynamic_pivot(central_query text, headers_query text)
 RETURNS refcursor AS
$$
DECLARE
  left_column text;
  header_column text;
  value_column text;
  h_value text;
  headers_clause text;
  query text;
  j json;
  r record;
  curs refcursor;
  i int:=1;
BEGIN
  -- find the column names of the source query
  EXECUTE 'select row_to_json(_r.*) from (' ||  central_query || ') AS _r' into j;
  FOR r in SELECT * FROM json_each_text(j)
  LOOP
    IF (i=1) THEN left_column := r.key;
      ELSEIF (i=2) THEN header_column := r.key;
      ELSEIF (i=3) THEN value_column := r.key;
    END IF;
    i := i+1;
  END LOOP;

  --  build the dynamic transposition query (based on the canonical model)
  FOR h_value in EXECUTE headers_query
  LOOP
    headers_clause := concat(headers_clause,
     format(chr(10)||',min(case when %I=%L then %I::text end) as %I',
           header_column,
       h_value,
       value_column,
       h_value ));
  END LOOP;

  query := format('SELECT %I %s FROM (select *,row_number() over() as rn from (%s) AS _c) as _d GROUP BY %I order by min(rn)',
           left_column,
       headers_clause,
       central_query,
       left_column);

  -- open the cursor so the caller can FETCH right away
  OPEN curs FOR execute query;
  RETURN curs;
END 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

then

```
=> BEGIN;

-- step 1: get the cursor (we let Postgres generate the cursor's name)
=> SELECT dynamic_pivot(
       'SELECT employee,ProductCategory,count(*) 
          FROM tbl GROUP BY employee,ProductCategory
          ORDER BY 1',
       'SELECT DISTINCT productCategory FROM tbl ORDER BY 1'
     ) AS cur
     \gset

-- step 2: read the results through the cursor
=> FETCH ALL FROM :"cur";
```

[Reference](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html)

Comment: The first query is exactly what I had in mind talking about a JSON document.

Comment: Yes, It is super easy and looks sufficient. any modern language can parse it, so it looks like totally usable

Comment: The second query is one of various 2-step techniques - but can be simpler for the case.

Comment: The second version worked great, exactly what I was looking to do. Had to modify it since my categories have spaces in them, but was quick and easy